# Plaid API. We didn't find any checking or savings accounts at this institution

Tags: api, plaid

I have a credit card from Citi bank but I have no checking or savings accounts in Citi bank.

I'm facing this error message when I try to get access to my credit card.

```
We didn't find any checking or savings accounts at this institution. Please try linking another institution
```

Is it possible to read balances and transactions from credit cards using Plaid API?

Should I use Liabilities API for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Liabilities API is designed for providing details of loans, like outstanding loan amount, APR, next payment due date, etc. If you are looking for transaction history and balance on a credit card account, you should use the Plaid Transactions API.

Hopefully that answered your question -- bank accounts and credit cards are separate so I am not completely sure what you are referring to in your question by "a bank account of my credit card".

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Alex's answer I've created a link for transactions:

```
https://{{env_url}}/link/token/create
   
{
    "client_id": "{{client_id}}",
    "secret": "{{secret_key}}",
    "client_name": "{{client_name}}",
    "country_codes": ["US"],
    "language": "en",
    "user": {
        "client_user_id": "{{client_user_id}}"
    },
    "products": ["transactions"] // <-------------
}
```

that allows me to get a public_token for my credit card

Answer (score -1):

The Plaid transactions API seems to not work for accounts like @Alex's, where he has a Credit Card, but no savings or checking account. Entering login information to link the Citi account results in a message that says "We didn't find any checking or savings accounts at this institution. Please try linking another institution."

Again this is using the Transactions API. Image of response show below:

[image]

Comment: Turns out I was passing in Auth when I thought I was only using the transactions API. I have confirmed that it is possible to query credit card transactions, just make sure your PLAID_PRODUCT fields are correct.